# Arranging values of array in Ascending order

Tags: c#

I couldn't get it to work, I am trying to arrange the values of the array in ascending order by using for loop.

```
        int[] arr = new int[5] { 5, 6, 2, 4, 1 };

        for (int i = 0; i <= arr.Length; i++)
        {
            if (arr[i] > arr[i + 1])
            {
                int temp = arr[i + 1];
                arr[i] = arr[i + 1];
                arr[i] = temp;
            }

            Console.Write(arr[i]);
        }
```

Comment: Any reason you don't want to use `Array.Sort`?

Comment: I think you need to read up on arrays, and how to index them.

Comment: I am new to programming, a few weeks back, I was able to do that but after a few, things seems to mess-up.

Comment: I think it's great that you are trying to learn - and calling Array.Sort won't help you learn much about programming/arrays. But if I tell you the answer you won't learn much either. You need to read some web pages/tutorials about arrays and how to index them, and experiment until you understand what is going on.

Comment: @user2864740: Actually it won't even get there, it will throw an exception already when `i == arr.Length - 1`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# sorting arrays in ascending and descending order](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30844241/c-sharp-sorting-arrays-in-ascending-and-descending-order)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am assuming that you are not using `Array.Sort` because you are doing this as a learning exercise; there is no other way to avoid this very common library function.

The reason your algorithm does not work is that it is not enough to go through an array once, and swap items that are out of order. Try doing this as a mental experiment, when the array is almost sorted, but the first element is at the end, like this:

```
2 3 4 5 6 7 1
```

A single path would bring you closer, but it wouldn't bring you all the way to a sorted array:

```
2 3 4 5 6 1 7
```

As you can see, you have to repeat this process multiple times, until the array is sorted. How do you know that the array is sorted? You know that when the entire inner loop did not have a single swap.

Here is how you can implement this:

```
bool didSwap;
do {
    didSwap = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length-1; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] > arr[i + 1])
        {
            int temp = arr[i + 1];
            arr[i + 1] = arr[i];
            arr[i] = temp;
            didSwap = true;
        }
    }
} while (didSwap);
for (int i = 0; i != arr.Length ; i++) {
    Console.Write(arr[i]);
}
```

Note several changes from your code:

- The printing is done in the separate loop, after the sorting is complete
- The loop goes to `arr.length-1`, not to `arr.length`, because otherwise your last check will go outside the bounds of the array.
- This sorting algorithm is called [*Bubble Sort*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort). There are various optimizations to this algorithm that can make it go slightly faster.
- In general, bubble sort is among the slower sorting algorithms. When the number of items to sort is high, you should consider an advanced algorithm, or use the library implementation.

Answer (score 4):

int[] Array = { 11, 33, 5, -3, 19, 8, 49 };

```
        int temp;

        for (int i = 0; i < Array.Length - 1; i++)
        {

            for (int j = i + 1; j < Array.Length; j++)
            {
                if (Array[i] > Array[j])
                {

                    temp = Array[i];
                    Array[i] = Array[j];
                    Array[j] = temp;

                }

            }

        }

        Console.Write("Sorted:");

        foreach (int sort in Array)
            Console.Write("{0} ", sort);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make your own sorting, then it's not enough to just loop through the items once and swap them. The closest to that is the [bubble sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort) algorithm, where you loop over the array repeatedly until there is no more items to swap:

```
int[] arr = new int[5] { 5, 6, 2, 4, 1 };

bool swapped = true;
while (swapped) {
  swapped = false;
  for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length - 1; i++) {
    if (arr[i] > arr[i + 1]) {
      swapped = true;
      int temp = arr[i + 1];
      arr[i] = arr[i + 1];
      arr[i] = temp;
   }
  }
}
for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length - 1; i++) {
  Console.Write(arr[i]);
}
```

There are also built in methods to sort data, which is easier to use, more efficient, and already thoroughly tested:

```
int[] arr = new int[5] { 5, 6, 2, 4, 1 };
Array.Sort(arr);
```

Comment: there is a typo where arr[i] is double assigned, one of them should be arr[i+1]

Answer (score 0):

Use Linq Order by:

```
int[] arr = new int[5] { 5, 6, 2, 4, 1 };

int[] ascOrderedArray = (from i in arr orderby i ascending select i).ToArray();
```

I think it could be easy and why do you need for loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
namespace bubble_sort
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program p = new Program();
            int[] arr = new int[50]; 
            int n;
            Console.WriteLine("Enter no of elements you want to store in an array");
            n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()); 
            Console.WriteLine("Enter elements in an array");
            for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
            {
                arr[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            }
            p.bubblesort(arr, n);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        public void bubblesort(int[] arr, int n)
        {
            int temp;
            for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 1; j <= n - i; j++)
                {
                    if (arr[j] > arr[j + 1])
                    {
                        temp = arr[j];
                        arr[j] = arr[j + 1];
                        arr[j + 1] = temp;
                    }
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Array after sorting");
            for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(arr[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It might be helpful to the person asking the question to describe why what they are doing doesn't work rather than just solving such a simple question for them.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
namespace basicsorting
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int i2, k, j;

            Console.WriteLine("How many elements you want to sort? ");

            i2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            int[] values = new int[i2];
            int n1 = 0;
            int n = 0; ;
            int i;
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the elements of array {0}", n1);
            for (i = 0; i < i2; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter the elements of array {0}");
                n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                Convert.ToInt32(values[i] = n);
            }

            for (i = 0; i < i2; i++)
            {
                k = Convert.ToInt32(values[i]);
                for (j = i - 1; j >= 0 && k < values[j]; j--)
                    values[j + 1] = values[j];
                values[j + 1] = k;
            }

            for (i = 0; i < i2; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("sorting elements {0}", values[i]);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

```
        int[] array = new int[] { 8, 9, 5, 6, 7, 4, 3, 2, 1 };
        int[] outPut = new int[] { };
        int temp = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < array.Length; j++)
            {
                var first = array[i];
                var second = array[j];
                if (array[i] < array[j]) {
                    temp = first;
                    array[i] = second;
                    array[j] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
        foreach (var item in array) {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
        }
        foreach (var item in array) {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    int temp = 0;
    int[] arr = new int[] { 5, 6, 2, 4, 1 };
    for (int i = 0; i <= arr.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j <= arr.Length - 1; j++)
        {
            if (arr[i] > arr[j])     //> Asecnding Order < Desending Order
            {
                temp = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = temp;
            }
        }
        Console.Write(arr[i]);
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   public int[] sortArray(params int[] numbers)

    {
        for(int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
        {
            for(int j = i + 1; j < numbers.Length; j++)
            {
                if (numbers[i] < numbers[j])
                {
                    continue;
                }else if (numbers[i] > numbers[j])
                {
                    int temp = numbers[i];
                    numbers[i] = numbers[j];
                    numbers[j] = temp;
                }


            }
        }

        return numbers;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You should do like :

int[] arr = new int[5] { 5, 6, 2, 4, 1 };

```
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length-1; i++)
        {
            if (arr[i] < arr[i + 1])
            {
                int temp = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[i + 1];
                arr[i + 1] = temp;
            }



        }
```

// to verify sorted Array

for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
            {
console.write( arr[i].ToString());
}

For last 1 you need not to check it will be automatically ordered.

Comment: I don't think this is proper bubble sort. The outer loop is supposed to exit as soon as it finds there are no values to swap. It isn't supposed to count up to the length of the array.

Comment: @Asad I was not implementing Bubble sort here. I was helping user to fix the problem in code. If there is need of optimization and complexity that will be taken care too. My objective was to fix issue raised in ques. Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

@Jon Skeet They wanted to use a for loop.

There are numerous types of sorts. The simplest is Bubble Sort.

```
int[] arr = new int[5] { 5, 6, 2, 4, 1 };

//bubble sort
for (int i = arr.Length - 1; i > 0; i--)
{
    for (int j = 0; j <= i - 1; j++)
    {
        if (arr[j] > arr[j + 1])
        {
            int highValue = arr[j];

            arr[j] = arr[j + 1];
            arr[j + 1] = highValue;
        }
    }
}

foreach(int i in arr) Console.Write(i);
```

Comment: I don't think this is proper bubble sort. The outer loop is supposed to exit as soon as it finds there are no values to swap. It isn't supposed to count up to the length of the array.

Comment: It does not matter if it does or does not. It is still a O(n^2) algorithm. This is for learning purposes. Preoptimisation is the root of all evil.

Comment: Yes, that's the worst case complexity of the algorithm, but there's no need to write code that performs useless iterations.

Comment: If you want to show the basics then you should use the original bubble sort algorithm, not a broken optimised variation of it.